# iOS clear caches ,simulator is effective,but when in real iPhone is not

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

iOS clear caches ,I delete the unuseful files use NSFileManager, but when I do it in simulator, it can clear all unuseful files, when I do it with a real iPhone(iPhone 5s),it was invalid, who can help me to solve this question? thank you very much!

code:

```
#define docPath [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]

#define cachePath [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]

- (void)clearCaches
{
    [self clearCachesWithFilePath:cachePath];
    NSArray *docFileArr = [self getAllFileNames:docPath];
    for (NSString * fileName in docFileArr) {        
        if (![fileName isEqualToString:@"mqtt.cer"]) {
            [self clearCachesWithFilePath:[docPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", fileName]]];
        }
    }
}

- (NSArray *)getAllFileNames:(NSString *)dirPath{
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil];
    return files;
}

- (BOOL)clearCachesWithFilePath:(NSString *)path{
    NSFileManager *mgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [mgr removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Use the `error` parameter instead of passing `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete the caches directory itself, instead get the list of contents in the caches directory and remove them one by one. Hope this helps.

Comment: I delete the  caches directory and which directory I get the list of contents is document directory, because of there is a certificate file I don't want to remove it. So I use a for loop and remove them one by one. Thank you all the same.

Comment: sorry,  no , it was strange